# `org-babel-load-file` doesn't always tangle source file

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm on Org 9.3. I run the following test.

```
[OP@localhost bug1]$ ls
real.org  test.org
```

The contents of `real.org` are:

```
[OP@localhost bug1]$ cat real.org
#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle yes

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq count (+ 1 count))
#+end_src
```

The contents of `test.org` are:

```
[OP@localhost bug1]$ cat test.org
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq count 0)
#+end_src

#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
(org-babel-load-file "real.org")
count
#+end_src
```

I then do:

```
[OP@localhost bug1]$ touch real.el
```

Now executing `test.org`, I get:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq count 0)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 0

#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
(org-babel-load-file "real.org")
count
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 0
```

And the file `real.el` is still empty. I have two questions:

- Why does this happen?
- Is there a way to force .el file regeneration every time?

Some further observations:

- If the org file being loaded (`real.org` in the above) is a symlink,
  the .el file is never regenerated.
- If the org file being loaded is newer, even if the .el file exists,
  the .el file will be regenerated.
- Finally, obviously if the .el file doesn't exist, it is created.

Answer (score 1):

`touch real.el` generates an empty file (if the file does not exist already) and gives it the current time as its modification time, so it is newer than `real.org`. Since it is newer, it will not be regenerated: `org-babel-load` [tangles only if the org file is newer](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/6a182b690fa81332f50327119e7183a0946d01a1/lisp/org.el#L227)[1].

So that gives you a few ways to ensure regeneration:

- delete `real.el` every time.
- touch `real.org` every time.
- add or delete a character to `real.org` and save it every time.
- open `real.org`, mark it modified with `(set-buffer-modified-p t)` and save it.

All of those make `real.el` either non-existent or older than `real.org` so it will be regenerated.

[1] Clicking on the link is supposed to take you to the definition of `org-babel-load-file` but it seems to take a while to do so: be patient (like wait-for-30-seconds patient). Not sure why it is so slow.